# Laravel service provider does not see the main class of my package

Tags: php, laravel

I got the service provider and my class for shopping cart.

This is my service provider:

```
<?php

namespace Alexxosipov\Cart;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart as Cart;

class CartServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {

    }

    public function register() {
        $this->app->singleton('cart', function() {
            return new Cart;
        });
    }
}
```

but my phpstorm says me, that `use Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart as Cart;` is never used in code. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I suspect you need to typehint it in your register callback

Comment: @user3647971 yes, you're right. Text it as answer, please :)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers, `public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(Connection::class, function ($app) {
            return new Connection(config('riak'));
        });
    }` The typehint occurs on first argument of singleton call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers), you need to type hint the Cart interface:

```
<?php

namespace Alexxosipov\Cart;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart as Cart;

class CartServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {

    }

    public function register() {
        $this->app->singleton(Cart::class, function() {
            return new Cart;
        });
    }
}
```